# Wordpress Theme Preloader page shows two different logos

Tags: themes, preloader, logos

I'm working with a Wordpress theme and am trying to track down why the pre-loader page is showing two versions of the logo?

We are live, I've looked at it stopped in dev tool on Chrome, but I'm still a newbie here.

http://www.labuvetteomaha.com/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbxTN.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your code, using a flag variable to get a signal notify if this context is home page or frontpage, and echo some tag include logo image.

Comment: Cheer with your great